# SSAS cube Alternative

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have application which does series of steps (14-19) and each step it posts the data to SSAS and update the source table. That updated data will be input for next step.

This application is written in VB and now we wanted to refactor to C#. Checking for any alternatives to do aggregation like SSAS cubes.

Any information/help, please post your answers/or any links.